# How to load dependent dlls in Java?

Tags: java, dll, native, jna

I have two dlls, `C:\foo\x.dll` and `C:\bar\y.dll`, where `x.dll` depends on `y.dll` (i.e. the implementation of functions in x will call functions in y).

In a Java application, when I load `x.dll` using JNA what do I need to set up to ensure that I don't get a `UnsatisfiedLinkException`?

I'm currently setting up `jna.library.path` to `C:\foo`, but it seems that it is not enough. Including both `C:\foo` and `C:\bar` in `java.library.path` also doesn't help.

Comment: You could try calling `System.loadLibrary("y")`

Comment: You don't need to load them at all. The dependent library just needs to be on the PATH, not the `java.library.path`.

Answer (score -1):

You can usually call `System.load("/name.dll")` with the path to your dependent library prior to making the JNA call to load the primary.

`System.loadLibrary("name")` will work if the library is on `java.library.path` and conforms to expected naming conventions.